# Android Studio 3 - how to test release build with JNI?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

How can I build and test release build in Android Studio 3? I am using JNI/NDK in my app, so I need to test if everything is builded correctly.

Comment: Perhaps a junit test call for your JNI code. I'm not sure what you are asking here.

Comment: @MorrisonChang how to force android studio to build release build that can be debugged in debugger

Comment: Release builds are for release not for debugging. The whole point of release builds is to apply proguard and remove any unnecessary files/debugging libraries to reduce size, improve speed, and make reverse engineering harder. That doesn't mean you couldn't create dummy/internal only release apps which check JNI functions, etc. and basically act as giant unit/integration tests. You'll have to modify your workflow to make sure they all 'pass'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No automation tools can fully replace traditional QA. See what happened recently to the Russian space launcher.

Regarding the specific case of an Android app with a native components, here are some issues to remember when it is ripe to switch from debug to release.

Obfuscation (proguard) can break JNI. To reduce the risks, I recommend to always resolve Java classes, fields and methods early in your native code, and write all JNI errors and exceptions to log.

Incorrect use of **visibility=hidden** can cause JNI to fail, too, but these mistakes are usually easy to catch.

You can and should begin with building your release app with debug verbose version of your native libraries.

This doesn't contradict the practice of building a debug version of the app with "release" optimized native binaries to understand performance issues early - the two *hybrid* app versions serve entirely different testing purposes.